# Can I use Materializecss with dart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dart

Google made some neat presets which can be found on http://materializecss.com/

I am mainly interested in the floating button, but I would like to know about the whole if I can use it with dart. The reason I worry is, because it consists not only of CSS and fonts but also of JS - and that requires JQuery to work, which I don't think I can bring to work with dart.
Or can I simply drop JQuery next to the Materialize-folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have tried recently, yes it can be used. Any css and javascript framework can be used from dart. jQuery/Materializecss javascript API might be tricky to use so you better get familiar with js interoperability. In my experiment I ended up switching to bootstrap and a css framework on top of it (currently investigating http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ and paper theme from bootswatch). While it might look less "material", I found the elements more mature (that is a pure personal opinion) and I have already a lot of js wrapper for jQuery and bootstrap .

Comment: And actually Material Design Lite, just released, sounds event a better option